# Роутер FastRoute. Передать объект в контроллер

Tags: php, php7, роутинг

Не могу передать объект в контроллер.

Роутер:

```
$r->addRoute('GET', '/user', 'MainController@index');
```

Контроллер:

```
use namespace\MyClass;

$myObject = new MyClass;

class MainController
{
    private $myObject;

    public function __construct(MyClass $myObject)
    {
        $this->myObject= $myObject;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'MainController...';
    }
}
```

Как это делается в php по классике?

Comment: По классике это делается контейнером зависимостей (Dependency Injection)

Comment: Хорошо, посмотрю